# Cannot compile C programs after deleting libc.a and libc.so

Tags: linux, data-recovery, c

I removed `libc.a` and `libc.so` files from my Raspberry Pi. I read somewhere that it was going to fix a problem i had with the `mpi.h` library, but instead of that it has prevented me from compiling C programs. This is the error message i get:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lc
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your distro, and thus on your package manager.

If you are on Debian and derivatives (Ubuntu, Mint,Raspbian,....) the command to find which package a given file belongs to is

```
  apt-file search filename
```

([**apt-file**](http://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=apt-file) is not installed by default, you will have to install it if you have not done so already). On my system, it says:

```
 # apt-file search /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so
 libc6-dev: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so
 # apt-file search /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.a
 libc6-dev: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.a
```

This shows that they originate from the *libc6-dev* package. Now you may force reinstallation with

```
 # apt-get --reinstall install libc6-dev
```

and you are done.